# How do I execute a command at a Snowball with a certain nbt data?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to execute a test command where every single snowball with a enchantment data of Fortune thrown spawns an armor stand with the NBT data I specified.

At first I tried to get the data of the snowball. by doing:

```
/execute as @e[type=minecraft:snowball] run data get entity @s
```

after I had thrown it.

Which worked and I got this as a result:
[image: Minecraft Nbt Data]

Which has the text `{Enchantments: [{lvl: 1s, id: "minecraft:fortune"}]}`

Which I tried to use to determine which snowball it was, by using this command

```
/tp @e[nbt={Enchantments: [{lvl: 1s, id: "minecraft:fortune"}]}] "Player Name"
```

But it says

> "No Entity was Found"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the full path: `/tp @e[nbt={Item:{tag:{Enchantments: [{lvl: 1s, id: "minecraft:fortune"}]}}}] "Player Name"`

Comment: Im gonna kiss you, thank you so much you have no idea how much this means to me